# call methods in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, class-method

I have this Try class:

```
function Try () {
  console.log('Start')
  this.Something( function() {
    console.log('asd')
    this.Some()
  })
}
Try.prototype.Something = function (callback) {
  console.log('hi all')
  callback()
}
Try.prototype.Some = function () {
  console.log('dsa')
}
```

But when I try to call the Some method in the callback part, it gives me an error, which says `this.Some is not a function`. What is the problem? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope of `this` is different inside a different `function`, even if it is inner `function`

you need to preserve `this` of outer function in `self` and make it

```
function Try () {
  console.log('Start')
  var self = this;
  self.Something( function() {
    console.log('asd')
    self.Some();
  })
}
```

Comment: or `.bind` the anonymous function to `this`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! :)

Comment: @Joe check the bind as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Creating_a_bound_function